# Disable / Remove Password for Login Wordpress

Tags: login, password

The use case is a small portal where elderly people can view their appointment(s) dates. The whole "using a password to login" set-up or navigate the forgotten password stuff is above their ability.

I would like to remove the password field and replace it with their First and Last name. So, when they want to login they have to type their First Name, Last Name, Email into the respective fields - No Password Needed.

Comment: If the appointment is anything medically related, you'll be violating HIPAA by allowing anyone who knows a person's first and last name to view their details.

Comment: Although not in the US and not medically related out of curiosity, if their password is technically their "email" would that get around the rule or no?

Comment: Anything that wouldn't actually be protected from an outsider would violate those types of U.S. laws. If it's information that someone else can know - i.e. all you need is an email address and first or last name, or especially if all you need is an email address - it's easy for someone other than the registered user to log in as them.